# Command substitution in command-line mode (ex mode) in Vim

Tags: vim

#### Short and simple example

How can I use shell like command substitution in the vim command-line mode?

For example, if I want to edit a particular path whose path is available as output of another command, say, `which foo`, I could do something like this on the shell.

```
vim "$(which foo)"
```

How can I do this with the `:e` command when I am already within Vim?

I am looking for something that is the equivalent of `:e $(which foo.txt)`.

#### Real use case

The above is just a short example so that this question makes sense for everyone. Here is the real reason why I am looking for this answer.

In the shell, I can execute `gdb -p $(pidof bar)` to attach to a process bar and debug it. With Vim, I am using ConqueGdb which accepts the same arguments as gdb, so I would want to do something like `:ConqueGdb -p $(pidof bar)` from within Vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:e `which foo`
:help backtick-expansion
```